# How to Oracle DBLink encryption

Tags: security, oracle-12c, encryption, dblink

I have the environment that I explain below and I need to encrypt the data that is sent between my two nodes, I have been reading but I can not find the right solution, I explain:
I have an Oracle Database 12c in which I have Advanced Security implemented through the netmgr but the encryption between the databases does not work, when putting a capture of the packages with tcpdump is shown in plain text when I use dblink, these dblinks are they use to load information from different sources (Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQL Server ... the latter using Oracle Gateway). How can I encrypt the communication between the source and the destination and vice versa to use the dblinks? Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you encrypt your Data? SQLnet native or via TLS? Can you post your sqlnet.ora?

Comment: SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER=REQUIRED
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER=(AES256)

Comment: SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT=REQUIRED
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT=(AES256)

Comment: Encrypt the data correctly with that configuration, for example connection from my pc to the server and vice versa, I verify it with tcpdump, but it does not happen that way when I use dblinks ... in that case the packages I capture are seen in plain text, oracle gateway does not have any option to encrypt connections ... it's weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to use Advanced Security, with netmgr or directly edit the sqlnet.ora by adding the parameters:

SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER = REQUIRED

SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER = (AES256)

SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT = REQUIRED

SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT = (AES256)

Once this is done it is necessary to restart the listener, for access to heterogeneous data base the sslmode = require parameter must be added in odbc.ini for postgresql, the ssl access must be previously configured in the postgres server and a registry with hostssl in the file pg_hba.conf ... I have not tried for sql server yet.
Regards